# How to Change the Title for a Second List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, naming

For my document, I have a List of Figures for the figures contained in the body of the text.  This has worked basically according to plan.  However, I also need to have a separate List of Figures for those that appear in the appendix.  Both of these appendices must be labelled "LIST OF [APPENDIX] FIGURES" on the first page and "LIST OF [APPENDIX] FIGURES (Continued)" on each subsequent page.

In order to change the heading, commands have been input to the style file:

```
\newcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
\newcommand\listfigurecont{LIST OF FIGURES (Continued)}
```

I tried to ameliorate the problem of both body and appendix figures ending up in the same list by using the caption package and:

```
\DeclareCaptionType{myfigure}[Figure]
```

then putting in my appendix figures like so:

```
\begin{myfigure}[htpb]
\centering
\psfragscanon
\psfrag{Batman}[][]{Primary}
\psfrag{Roof Disp.}[][]{$Roof Disp. (in)$}
\psfrag{Roof Acc.}[][]{$Roof Acc. (g)$}
\psfrag{Robin}[][]{Secondary}
\psfrag{Time (s)}[][]{$Time (s)$}
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{RDCHY034.eps}
\caption{Mean roof displacement response, Chi Chi CHY034 motion, founded on dense sand.}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{RACHY034.eps}
\caption{Mean roof acceleration response, Chi Chi CHY034 motion, founded on dense sand.}
\end{myfigure}
```

These figures look good.  Everything but the title of the list is set.

Here's the code I used for the Figures and Tables:

```
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures 
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF APPENDIX FIGURES}
\renewcommand\listfigurecont{LIST OF APPENDIX FIGURES (Continued)}
\listofmyfigures 
%\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF APPENDIX FIGURES}
%\renewcommand\listfigurecont{LIST OF APPENDIX FIGURES (Continued)}
\clearpage
```

The results are kind of freaky.  If I only have one page of appendix figures, the title reads "LIST OF APPENDIX FIGURES" no problem.  If it comes out to more than one page of appendix figures, the first page reads, "List of Myfigures," any middle pages correctly read "LIST OF APPENDIX FIGURES (Continued)," and the last page reads, "LIST OF TABLES (Continued)."

I've tried a wide variety of things and none seem to change anything.  Any help would be appreciated.  This is all but my last resort before I type out a list of appendix figures in Word and slide it into my document.

Comment: Please give us a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 5):

No need to define a new kind of float. Here's one possibility: I defined a `\listofappfigures` command that is completely analogous to `\listoffigures`, but using an external file `.laf` for the figures and a different name. The trick is simply to change the extension for the figures from `.lof` to `.laf` at the beginning of the appendices, and this can be done with a redefinition of `\ext@figure`. Also, `\@chapter` was patched so that each chapter adds a little vertical spacing to the new list (as with the default LoF). The afterpage package was used to create the title for the second page; allyou have to do is to say

```
\addtocontents{laf}{\protect\afterpage{\bfseries\listappfigurecont\par\vskip20pt}}
```

somewhere in the appendices, after the first few figures.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand\listappfigurename{LIST OF APPENDIX FIGURES}
\newcommand\listappfigurecont{{\LARGE LIST OF FIGURES (Continued)}}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}\addtocontents{laf}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}

\newcommand\listofappfigures{%
  \renewcommand\listfigurename{\listappfigurename}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{laf}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother

\newcommand\testfig{%
  \begin{figure}\caption{Caption for the figure~\thefigure}\end{figure}\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listofappfigures

\chapter{Some Chapter}
\testfig
\testfig
\testfig

\chapter{Some Chapter}
\testfig
\testfig

\appendix
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ext@figure{laf}
\makeatother

\chapter{Some Appendix}
\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig
\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig
\addtocontents{laf}{\protect\afterpage{\bfseries\listappfigurecont\par\vskip20pt}}
\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig
\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig
\chapter{Some Other Appendix}
\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig
\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig
\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig
\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig
\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig\testfig

\end{document}
```

An image of the standard LoF:

[image]

And an image of the new list of figures showing the continued title in the second page:

[image]